# What is a good way to restart a game?

Tags: python, pygame

So right now, i have a platformer and i want to make it so when i click on a button, the whole game restarts.

In `main.py`:

```
level=Level(level_map,screen)
while running:
    if game_state=='game_active':
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                pygame.font.quit()
                sys.exit()
        level.run()
        screen.blit(sky_surface,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

in `level.py`:

```
class Level:
    def __init__(self,level_data,surface):
        self.display_surface=surface
        self.level_building(level_data)
    def level_building(self,tilesheet):
        self.coins=pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player=pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
        for row_index,row in enumerate(level_map):
            for col_index,cell in enumerate(row):
                self.x=col_index*tile_size
                self.y=row_index*tile_size
                if cell=='R':
                    self.coin_sprite=Recyclables((self.x+22,self.y+55))
                    self.coins.add(self.coin_sprite)
                if cell=='P':
                    self.player_sprite=Player((self.x+10,self.y))
                    self.player.add(self.player_sprite)
    def collisions(self):
        playercoin=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.coins,self.player,True,False) # kills the coin (to show it has been picked up)
        if len(playercoin)==1:
            self.score+=1
    def run(self):
        self.coins.draw(self.display_surface)
        self.collisions()
        self.player.draw(self.display_surface)
```

After my game finishes running, what is a good way to restart everything, and respawn all the sprites that were killed? (did not show the kill code since it'd be too long) so far i've tried killing all sprites after the game but i don't know how to re-draw everything.

Comment: You aren't showing how `self.player` is a thing for `Level`, so it's getting increasingly hard to help with only partial information.

Comment: yeah sorry updated it once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PyGame, you're in full control of what's being drawn on the screen every frame, so I'm not sure why you wouldn't be sure how to redraw things.

Since you apparently have already encapsulated your game logic into the `Level` class, restarting the level shouldn't require more than just

```
level = Level(level_map, screen)
```

so subsequent calls to `level.run()` use a fresh level.

(Also, unless you're doing esoteric things that you're not showing us here, you shouldn't necessarily need to even "kill sprites".)

Comment: I didn't show it but level.run is just for drawing the sprite. I don't know how to re add the killed sprites back into the group after though that's what i meant by re draw sorry if it was not the right word

Comment: With your edit, I'm still not sure what's the issue here, as your `Level` seems to encapsulate your game objects just fine. Did you try my suggestion of just replacing the `Level`?

Comment: nevermind, your suggestion worked, thanks i just mis read it and didn't know what to do with it.

Comment: All of your sprites are referred to only in the `Level`, so they will be cleaned up by Python.